# How can I use vim not vi to write commit message?

Tags: mercurial

When I do hg commit, it use vi as my default editor, how to change it to vim?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

From the [editor docs](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/editor):

> Mercurial tries to pick which program
>   to call to edit a commit message by
>   trying the following (in order):
>
> 1. HGEDITOR environment variable
> 2. editor configuration option in [ui] section (in hgrc or passed with
>      --config ui.editor command-line option).
> 3. VISUAL environment variable
> 4. EDITOR environment variable
> 5. vi, if none of the above is set

Personally I prefer to just do `hg commit -m "My commit message"`

Comment: +1. I'd go with [ui] in hgrc. -m will of course always work, no matter what editor you configured.

Comment: I don't have an `.hgrc` file on WIndows 7, and I still don't get how to set the default commit editor, will edit when I figure out.

Answer (score 33):

Find your .hgrc file in your home directory and add the following line:

```
editor=vim
```

That should do it.

So let's say you use nano for cases like this. Your .hgrc file would read something like:

```
[ui]
username = Bob Jones <Bob.Jones@gmail.com>
editor=nano
```

Pretty simple

Answer (score 7):

Probably set the EDITOR environment variable: `EDITOR=vim`

> Whenever you hg commit, mercurial will create a file like
>   /tmp/hg-editor-mX1MbE.txt and invoke $EDITOR on it. Because
>   the file already has contents, many editors will create a
>   backup file /tmp/hg-editor-mX1MbE.txt~ or similar. The
>   actual temp file hg wants to use (/tmp/hg-editor-mX1MbE.txt)
>   is later removed, but the backup files stay around.

(source : [debian bug reports](http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=472943)

Answer (score 2):

[List of ways to do it](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/editor), with the most common being definition of different environmental variables like `HGEDITOR`, `VISUAL`, or `EDITOR`.